# SQL DateTime Conversion Error on Update Command

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio-2015

trying to update existing entries in my SQL database from Visual Studio using Stored Procedures. The error I get when debugging the actual SQL statement is:

```
Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character string.
```

Even when I stub in both NULL or proper time formats. 
Here's the SQL Code

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[SP_UpdateQuery] (
        @NewName NVARCHAR(25) = NULL,
        @Name NVARCHAR(25) = NULL,
        @Surname NVARCHAR(25) = NULL,
        @NewSurname NVARCHAR(25) = NULL,
        @CompanyName NVARCHAR(25) = NULL,
        @NewCompanyName NVARCHAR(25) = NULL,
        @Address NVARCHAR(35) = NULL,
        @NewAddress NVARCHAR(35) = NULL,
        @MobileNo NVARCHAR(12) = NULL,
        @NewMobileNo NVARCHAR(12) = NULL,
        @PhoneNo NVARCHAR(12) = NULL,
        @NewPhoneNo NVARCHAR(12) = NULL,
        @Email NVARCHAR(40) = NULL,
        @NewEmail NVARCHAR(40) = NULL,
        @AreaCode NVARCHAR(10) = NULL,
        @NewAreaCode NVARCHAR(10) = NULL,
        @DateTime DateTime = NULL,
        @NewDateTime DateTime = NULL
        )
AS
UPDATE [dbo].[CUSTOMERS]
SET Name = @NewName, Surname = @NewSurname, Email = @NewEmail, MobileNo = @NewMobileNo, PhoneNo = @NewPhoneNo,
    CompanyName = @NewCompanyName, Address = @NewAddress, AreaCode = @NewAreaCode, DateTime = @NewDateTime
WHERE (@Name IS NULL OR Name LIKE '%' + @Name + '%')
      AND (@Surname IS NULL OR Surname LIKE '%' + @Surname + '%')
      AND (@Email IS NULL OR Email LIKE '%' + @Email + '%')
      AND (@MobileNo IS NULL OR MobileNo LIKE '%' + @MobileNo + '%')
      AND (@PhoneNo IS NULL OR PhoneNo LIKE '%' + @PhoneNo + '%')
      AND (@Address IS NULL OR Address LIKE '%' + @Address + '%')
      AND (@CompanyName IS NULL OR CompanyName LIKE '%' + @CompanyName + '%')
      AND (@Email IS NULL OR Email LIKE '%' + @Email + '%')
      AND (@AreaCode IS NULL OR AreaCode LIKE '%' + @AreaCode + '%')
      AND (@DateTime IS NULL OR DateTime LIKE '%' + @DateTime + '%')
```

Existing time entries in the table are as such

```
2016-11-10 00:00:00.000
```

Again, the error occurs when actually debugging the SQL, so nothing to fix in Visual Studio just yet.

My test cases have been allowing the Time variables to default to NULL and also inputting these values

```
@DateTime = N'2016-11-10T00:00:00',
@NewDateTime = N'1900-01-01T01:01:01'
//New Test Case
@DateTime = N'1900-01-01 00:00:00',
@NewDateTime = N'1900-01-01 01:01:01'
```

The most similar questions I could find ended up being errors in C# Code, but since the SQL is actually bugging out here, could use some help. Thanks for you time!

Comment: Which database is it? I think the problem is with this line `AND (@DateTime IS NULL OR DateTime LIKE '%' + @DateTime + '%') ` because it is not a `string`, so you shouldn't use 'LIKE` on datetime. Remove the `OR` part and try again.

Comment: Thank you so much Utsav! That was exactly my problem. I was using my own database, if that clarifies anything for future users?
Thanks again!!

Comment: Glad it worked. I put this as answer. Please accept it so the question can be closed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned in comment, Replace

```
AND (@DateTime IS NULL OR DateTime LIKE '%' + @DateTime + '%')
```

with

```
AND @DateTime IS NULL
```